# Помогите составить простенький запрос SQL

Tags: запрос, sql-server

База состоит из двух таблиц

```
Department
--- id (int primary key)
--- name (varchar)
--- parent (int)

Users
--- Id
--- name
--- department_id
```

Этот запрос вытаскивает все отделы.

```
SELECT t1.name AS lvl1, t2.name as lvl2, t3.name as lvl3
FROM Department AS t1
LEFT JOIN Department AS t2 ON t2.parent = t1.id
LEFT JOIN Department AS t3 ON t3.parent = t2.id
```

**Но никак не могу сообразить. Как вывести и пользователей в этот запрос**

Answer (score 1):

Я б воспользовался рекурсивным выражением ([Recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243(v=sql.105).aspx))

```
with dep_rec(DepId, Lvl)
as
(
    select id, 1 from Department where parent is null
    union all
    select id, lvl+1 from Department 
    join dep_rec on dep_rec.DepId = parent
)
select 
   Department.id
   , Department.Name
   , Lvl
   , Users.Id
   , Users.Name
from dep_rec 
join Department on Department.id = DepId
join Users on Users.department_id = Department.id
```

Тем самым мы не ограничиваем количество вложеностей 3я, плюс вопрос в поставленном виде не совсем имеет смысл (непонятно куда там прикручивать пользователя)